# Saving information to an app's sandbox when downloaded from the app store?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios5.1

How do you create an app that already has information loaded in its sandbox when downloaded from the app store, instead of being created and saved to its sandbox at first launch on the ios device?

Comment: The application's bundle is part of its sandbox, so anything you have copied into the resources is, by definition, part of the sandbox.  What is it you actually want to have happen to this information?

Comment: I want to have a dictionary with some names coupled to default values, so basically how would I go about have a dictionary in the resources?

Answer (score 0):

Create a .plist file and add it to your project.  By default, the root object of a plist is a dictionary.  At run time, locate the file in your main bundle and use `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` to load it.